# How to send JSON request with javascript and receive it in Flask?

Tags: javascript, forms, flask, python-requests

I've written a form that has a n amount of steps, and after parsing the data into string object (to put inside the request body) inside JavaScript, I want to load it up and send it to my Flask backend server.

```
{
"0": {
    "function": "go_to_url",
    "values": {
        "url": "https://valid.url/"
    }
},
"1": {
    "function": "refresh",
    "values": {
        "amount": "5"
    }
},
"2": {
    "function": "take_screenshot",
    "values": {
        "name": "screenshotname"
    }
},
"3": {
    "function": "send_keys_to_element",
    "values": {
        "xpath": "//*[@value='login']",
        "keysToSend": "loginname"
    }
},
"4": {
    "function": "assert_element_exist",
    "values": {
        "xpath": "//button[@login]"
    }
}
}
```

This is what I want to send with onclick function within a button inside mentioned form. My Js call looks like this

function submitScenario() {

```
    const steps = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('scenario-creation-step'));
    const data = {};


    for (const c in steps) {


        var currentStep_dict = {};
        currentStep_dict['function'] = steps[c].childNodes[0].value;

        let inputs = Array.from(steps[c].childNodes[1].getElementsByTagName('input'));

        var values = {};
        for (const i in inputs) {
            values[inputs[i].getAttribute('data')] = inputs[i].value;
        }
        currentStep_dict['values'] = values;

        data[c] = currentStep_dict;
    }

    var dataJson = JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log(dataJson);

    fetch(window.location.href + 'ed', 
        {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type':'application/json',
            },
            body: dataJson,
        }
    );

}
```

The form presents itself like that, with url set for 'scenario_added'

```
<form action="{{ url_for('scenario_added') }}" method="post" name="scenarioForm">

<!-- inputs hidden for data being fetched from flask -->
<input type="hidden" id="scenario_name" value="{{ scenario_details[0] }}" />
<input type="hidden" id="expected" value="{{ scenario_details[1] }}" />
<input type="hidden" id="author_id" value="{{ scenario_details[2] }}" />
<input type="hidden" id="steps_to_show" value="{{ step_names }}" />


<div id="scenario-creation-table" class="scenario-creation-table">
    <button type="button" id="add_step">Add a step</button>
    <!-- steps show here -->
</div>

<div class="scenario-creation-submitbuttons">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <input type="button" id="download_json" value="Pobierz scenariusz">
    <input type="submit" id="submit_scenario_button" value="Dodaj Scenariusz" onclick="submitScenario()">
</div>
```

The view for scenario_added looks as follows:

```
@app.route("/scenario_added", methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def scenario_added():

    if request.method == "GET":
        return '<h6>bad request, it was get for /scenario_added</h6>' #TODO 404


    scenario_data = request.json
    return render_template('scenario_added.html', data = scenario_data)
```

Unfortunately, after sending such request, I'm presented with "Bad Request

Did not attempt to load JSON data because the request Content-Type was not 'application/json'."

Even though, when I send the request via POSTMAN on the url, I receive a 200 Code with expected result of the html view containing the data.

How should I rearrange the form or JavaScript function so it will send a request with data gathered from the form?

Comment: Are you sure data is json? And are you sending the same request via Postman, same body and same url?

Comment: The data itself is a stringified JSON, but it is a valid json - as stated in "var dataJson = JSON.stringify(data);" line

Comment: Since you have onclick on submit_scenario_button, why did you do this: action="{{ url_for('scenario_added') }}"?. try to remove it.